# Get object information of selected listbox item

Tags: c#, winforms

I have objects in my list box that contain an instance of the `BankAccount` class (Balance, transfer, Withdraw methods) and `Wallet` class (name, birthday, etc.)
I need to view certain parts of information (like balance) about the selected list box object (lbAccounts).

Objects in Listbox:

```
DateTime birth = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1970");

Wallet account = new Wallet("Bob", "Smith", birth);
BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount(account);
account1.DepositFunds(5000);
BankAccount account2 = new BankAccount(account);
account2.DepositFunds(300);

//Adding accounts to listbox
lbAccounts.Items.Add(account1);
lbAccounts.Items.Add(account2);
```

**QUESTION:**  How do I get the balance of a selected listbox object?

Comment: WPF? WebForms? WinForms? ASP.NET MVC? ...?

Comment: Parse / cast the selected listbox object result to a type of [BankAccount]?

Comment: webform, C# and VS 2015

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will get the object from selected item of list box.

```
BankAccount ba = lbAccounts.SelectedItem as BankAccount;
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it simply by using the following operation:

```
BankAccount currentAccount= lbAccounts.SelectedItem as BankAccount;
```

But I prefer you to create a List of `BankAccount` and bind the listbox using this list. so that you can easily took the selected item from the list: consider the code below:

```
List<BankAccount> AccountList= new List<BankAccount>();
AccountList.Add(new BankAccount(){fName="Bob", lName="Smith", dob=birth });
AccountList.Add(new BankAccount(){fName="foo", lName="bar", dob=birth });
//Populate the list here
// Bind the list box according to the type of application you are using
// here i use asp.net
lbAccounts.DataTextField = "fName";
lbAccounts.DataValueField = "fName";
lbAccounts.DataBind();
```

SO the binding part is over now we need to get the business object back from the Listbox according to the selectedItem

```
IList<BankAccount> boundList = (IList<BankAccount>)lbAccounts.DataSource;
BankAccount currentAccount= boundList[lbAccounts.SelectedIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the selected listbox to a `BankAccount` object - then use the properties as you'd like.

```
var balance = ((BankAccount)lbAccounts.SelectedItem).Balance
```

Bonus MSDN link: [How to: Convert a ListBoxItem to a New Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749147(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can safe cast the `SelectedItem` property of `ListBox`.

But make sure that `SelectedItem` is not `null`. If there is no selected item on the list this property will be `null`.

```
var selected = listBox1.SelectedItem as Account;
if (selected != null)
; // use it
```