# Access other properties of selected Listbox item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have searched and searched for an answer to this problem. I thought I came close by finding this post: 
[Get object information of selected listbox item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995639/get-object-information-of-selected-listbox-item)

But I keep getting a an "invalid cast exception" error at this part in the code:

```
string m = ((Customer)LBox.SelectedItem).ID;
```

Here is most of my code thus far, where I add the listbox items from a Dataclass (linq to SQL). Where I am stuck is that I'd like to get the DB_ID of the record that I have selected in the Listbox.

I have a workaround where I can do another SQL query on the DB with the customer's name that is the LBox.SelectedItem value, but i figure I must be doing something wrong to not be able to cast the SelectedItem value back to Customer to get the ID?

I am just starting out in C# and know practically nothing, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString);

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var q = from accts in dc.Customers where accts.SysStatus == "Active" orderby accts.Customer select accts;

    if (dc.DatabaseExists())
        foreach (Customer c in q)
            LBox.Items.Add(c.Customer);
}

public void LBox_SelectionChanged (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lblComp.Content = LBox.SelectedItem;
    string m = ((Customer)LBox.SelectedItem).ID;
}
```

I think @Boxed help me out here.

I modified the code as follows:

```
foreach (Surgeon c in q)
   LBox.Items.Add(c);
   LBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Customer";
```

Then I was able to obtain the values from the Customers Class as such:

```
string m = ((Customers)LBox.SelectedItem).ID;
lblComp.Content = ((Customers)LBox.SelectedItem).Customer;
txtDetails.Text = m;
```

Is this code ideal, or should I be doing something else?

Comment: I would suggest you to take another step, just for help in debugging: declare a `var selectedItem = LBox.SelectedItem;` before `string m`, put a breakpoint on it and check its value.

Comment: What is the datatype of `c.Customer`? If it is a string then you can not cast it to Customer by doing `((Customer)LBox.SelectedItem)`. The best is to set the  DataSource property of ListBox to `q.ToList()` by `LBox.DataSource = q.ToList();` and also set ValueMember property of listbox to `"ID"` and DisplayMember property to `"Customer"`. `LBox.ValueMember = "ID";` and `LBox.DisplayMember = "Customer;`

Comment: Weird context. You got a `Customer` class within `Customer` and its a collection? I think you only need `LBox.Items.Add(c)`

Comment: I found the code that corrected my problem. I think @Boxed helped understand what I was doing wrong, but I'd like to know if I'm coding this correctly, and why certain attributes or properties are not available to my context.