# How to extract selected item from Listbox as an object

Tags: c#

How to extract a selected item from Listbox as an object. Currently, I'm taking all records from DB and I add them to the Listbox in the following way:

```
                var allEmployees = GetAll();
                foreach (var emp in allEmployees)
                {
                    var empFull = $"{emp.Id} - {emp.Name} {emp.Surname} - {emp.Email}";
                    listBoxViewEmp.Items.Add(empFull);
                }
```

However, I find it challenging to make the listBoxViewEmp.SelectedItem to object since I'm taking the entire string that contains id, name, surname, and email.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBoxViewEmp.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var newForm = new UpdateForm(listBoxViewEmp.SelectedItem);
        newForm.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select employee first");
    }

}
```

What is the best way to handle this kind of issue?

Update:
Here is my attempt, but I got only objects now in the listbox

```
                var allEmployees = GetAll();
                foreach (var emp in allEmployees)
                {
                    var empFull = (Employee)emp;
                    listBoxViewEmp.Items.Add(empFull);
                }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lo3h.png)

Comment: `SelectedItem` is _already_ an `Object`. If by "object", you mean a _specific_ type, cast it. E.g., `(Employee)listBoxViewEmp.SelectedItem`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get object information of selected listbox item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995639/get-object-information-of-selected-listbox-item)

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine The item is a string (see where they add `empFull`?) You **can't just cast a string to an Employee** specific type.  I think this is a matter of adding to the ListBox a _wrapper object_ that overrides ToString that will present the Employee object in the desired way (or perhaps just overriding ToString for the Employee itself)

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'JustTest.Models.Employee'.'  -- This is my first C# forms application

Comment: @Wyck Ah, you're right; didn't notice.

Comment: @LirkaMonteo See Wyck's comment above. You should add the employee object directly to the list and override its `ToString()` method so that it's formatted as desired in the ListBox. For example, add `public override string ToString() => $"{Id} - {Name} {Surname} - {Email}";` to your `Employee` class, then, when you're adding items to the ListBox, it needs to be just `listBoxViewEmp.Items.Add(emp);`.

Comment: I guess the best way is to get the Id from listBoxViewEmp.SelectedItem and make another request to DB to pull the record :(

Answer (score 0):

The string that appears for any object added as an item to a ListBox control will be the return value of the `ToString` method of that object.  In your case, you added a string directly to the list. So there's (likely) no way to recover the original object from the formatted string you created for that object.

Instead, override `ToString` for your Employee object (if appropriate to do so).

---

Alternatively, you can create a wrapper class whose job it is to remember the original object and to provide a custom `ToString` implementation for the remembered object. Such a generic formatter class might look like:

```cs
public class Formatter<T>
{
    public Formatter(T obj, Func<T, string> fnFormat)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.fnFormat = fnFormat;
    }
    public T obj;
    public Func<T, string> fnFormat;
    public override string ToString() => fnFormat(obj);
}
```

Then, when you add items to the list box, add a Formatter wrapping that item instead.  Its `ToString` method will be called, which will call the custom formatter for that item.

```cs
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    this.listBox1.Items.Add(new Formatter<Employee>(employee,
        emp => $"{emp.Id} - {emp.Name} {emp.Surname} - {emp.Email}"));
}
```

And to access the original Employee, case the SelectedItem back to the `Formatter<Employee>` and access its remembered object field `obj`.  Now you have the original Employee object back (or DB record or entity or whatever it was originally.)  Example usage:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Employee employee = (this.listBox1.SelectedItem as Formatter<Employee>)?.obj;
    this.label1.Text = employee?.Id.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use databinding for this. Make a new readonly property which will return computed string you want. Than `ListBox` has some properties you can use:

- `Datasource` - source of data which will be displayed. You can set here just simple `List<Employee>`.
- `DisplayMember` - you set the name of the property, which value you want to see in the `ListBox`.
- `ValueMember` - you set the name of the property which value you want to get for selected item using ListBox's `SelectedValue` property.

So you can do it this way:

```cs
// You should set these two properties in form's designer.
listBoxViewEmp.DisplayMember = "Info"; // "Info" is that new readonly property.
listBoxViewEmp.ValueMember = "Id";

var allEmployees = GetAll().ToList();
listBoxViewEmp.DataSource = allEmployees;
```

That's it. Now:

- You will see in the listbox what you want to see there.
- `listBox.SelectedItem` returns whole your `Eployee` object.
- `listBox.SelectedValue` returns the `Id` value of selected employee.

Comment: I tried that way and in the Listbox, the items are shown as Just Test.Models.Employee

Comment: @LirkaMonteo This is s fully functional example: https://github.com/satano/so-72502018-listbox

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Employee class, do that :

Main code:

```
var allEmployees = GetAll();
foreach (var emp in allEmployees)
{
     var empFull = (Employee)emp;
     listBoxViewEmp.Items.Add(empFull);
}
```

In class code :

```
class Employee
{
     ...
     public override string ToString()
     {
          return $"{this.Id} - {this.Name} {this.Surname} - {this.Email}";
     }
}
```

Now you are able to get the items from the listbox as Employee and it will also replace "JustTest.Models.Employee" in the ToString above.